# dplyr filter condition to distinguish between unicode symbol and its unicode representation

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, stringi

I am trying to filter the Symbol column based on whether it's of the form `\uxxxx`

This is easy visually, that is, some look like `$`, `¢`, `£`, and others like `\u058f`, `\u060b`, `\u07fe`.

But I cannot seem to figure it out using `stringi` / `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

df <- structure(list(Character = c("\\u0024", "\\u00A2", "\\u00A3", 
                             "\\u00A4", "\\u00A5", "\\u058F", "\\u060B", "\\u07FE", "\\u07FF", 
                             "\\u09F2", "\\u09F3", "\\u09FB", "\\u0AF1", "\\u0BF9", "\\u0E3F", 
                             "\\u17DB", "\\u20A0", "\\u20A1", "\\u20A2", "\\u20A3"), 
                     Symbol = c("$", "¢", "£", "¤", "¥", "\u058f", "\u060b", "\u07fe", "\u07ff", 
                                "৲", "৳", "\u09fb", "\u0af1", "\u0bf9", "฿", "៛", "₠", 
                                "₡", "₢", "₣")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

   Character Symbol
1    \\u0024      $
2    \\u00A2      ¢
3    \\u00A3      £
4    \\u00A4      ¤
5    \\u00A5      ¥
6    \\u058F \u058f
7    \\u060B \u060b
8    \\u07FE \u07fe
9    \\u07FF \u07ff
10   \\u09F2      ৲
11   \\u09F3      ৳
12   \\u09FB \u09fb
13   \\u0AF1 \u0af1
14   \\u0BF9 \u0bf9
15   \\u0E3F      ฿
16   \\u17DB      ៛
17   \\u20A0      ₠
18   \\u20A1      ₡
19   \\u20A2      ₢
20   \\u20A3      ₣
```

#### What I've tried

I have tried using variations on `nchar` but haven't had luck

```
df$Symbol %>% nchar
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

df$Symbol %>% stri_unescape_unicode %>% nchar
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

df$Symbol %>% stri_escape_unicode %>% nchar
# [1] 1 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

#### Question

How can I filter on the Symbol column for all the rows of the form `$`, `¢`, `£` etc (and conversely for rows like `\u058f`, `\u060b`, `\u07fe`)?

Comment: Did you try use Regex in this case?

Comment: @vpz I haven't, no. I reasoned there would be some 'more formal' way of doing it, but will gladly use regex if it works reliably!

Comment: Does the character representation have some pattern for the symbols?

Comment: @vpz the only info is what's contained in the `Symbol` column (I feel like it *should* be enough, but I can't work out how to distinguish - which is interesting because it's so easy for human eyes to see)

Comment: Are all those valid unicodes? You can try the solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794201/search-for-unicode-values-in-character-string

Comment: @RonakShah thanks I’ll read up. It’s possible they are some superset of Unicode or also possible that Unicode is the wrong term, and a third possibility is that the Symbol column is a mixture of Unicode and something else.

Comment: All of those symbols are valid unicode.  So as you might have gathered from H1's answer, the result will be completely font dependent.

Comment: @thc thanks, how are you able to tell, is there a function in R that returns `TRUE`/`FALSE` as to whether it's valid unicode, or is there another way?

Comment: You can use `utf8::utf8_valid()` but this may not distinguish between existing valid unicode and unicode that is valid but unassigned. Can you expand a little on what you're ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: @stevec I looked up each character code online, but the utf8 function H1 mentioned is probably better :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**

The function `glyphs_match()` from the `gdtools` package is designed for this, however, using it didn't quite return the expected result.  I'm using `Lucida Console` as my font and obtain the following output when using `glyphs_match()`.  There seems to be one glyph that isn't rendered but for which the function returns `TRUE`.  Perhaps other users can explain why that is the case.

```
df$glyph_match <- gdtools::glyphs_match(df$Symbol, fontfile = "C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\lucon.TTF")
    df

   Character   Symbol glyph_match
1    \\u0024        $        TRUE
2    \\u00A2        ¢        TRUE
3    \\u00A3        £        TRUE
4    \\u00A4        ¤        TRUE
5    \\u00A5        ¥        TRUE
6    \\u058F <U+058F>       FALSE
7    \\u060B <U+060B>       FALSE
8    \\u07FE <U+07FE>       FALSE
9    \\u07FF <U+07FF>       FALSE
10   \\u09F2 <U+09F2>       FALSE
11   \\u09F3 <U+09F3>       FALSE
12   \\u09FB <U+09FB>       FALSE
13   \\u0AF1 <U+0AF1>       FALSE
14   \\u0BF9 <U+0BF9>       FALSE
15   \\u0E3F <U+0E3F>       FALSE
16   \\u17DB <U+17DB>       FALSE
17   \\u20A0 <U+20A0>       FALSE
18   \\u20A1        ¢        TRUE
19   \\u20A2 <U+20A2>       FALSE
20   \\u20A3 <U+20A3>        TRUE
```

**Earlier answer - may only work on Windows:**

There will be variation depending on your font/system, for example, when running your code my output doesn't match what you've provided:

```
df <- structure(list(Character = c("\\u0024", "\\u00A2", "\\u00A3", 
                             "\\u00A4", "\\u00A5", "\\u058F", "\\u060B", "\\u07FE", "\\u07FF", 
                             "\\u09F2", "\\u09F3", "\\u09FB", "\\u0AF1", "\\u0BF9", "\\u0E3F", 
                             "\\u17DB", "\\u20A0", "\\u20A1", "\\u20A2", "\\u20A3"), 
                     Symbol = c("$", "¢", "£", "¤", "¥", "\u058f", "\u060b", "\u07fe", "\u07ff", 
                                "৲", "৳", "\u09fb", "\u0af1", "\u0bf9", "฿", "៛", "₠", 
                                "₡", "₢", "₣")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

df
   Character   Symbol
1    \\u0024        $
2    \\u00A2        ¢
3    \\u00A3        £
4    \\u00A4        ¤
5    \\u00A5        ¥
6    \\u058F <U+058F>
7    \\u060B <U+060B>
8    \\u07FE <U+07FE>
9    \\u07FF <U+07FF>
10   \\u09F2 <U+09F2>
11   \\u09F3 <U+09F3>
12   \\u09FB <U+09FB>
13   \\u0AF1 <U+0AF1>
14   \\u0BF9 <U+0BF9>
15   \\u0E3F <U+0E3F>
16   \\u17DB <U+17DB>
17   \\u20A0 <U+20A0>
18   \\u20A1        ¢
19   \\u20A2 <U+20A2>
20   \\u20A3 <U+20A3>
```

But one crude way of capturing if the glyph exists is:

```
 nchar(capture.output(cat(df$Symbol, sep = "\n"))) == 1

[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[18]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

So the glyphs can be filtered by:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(nchar(capture.output(cat(Symbol, sep = "\n"))) == 1)

  Character Symbol
1   \\u0024      $
2   \\u00A2      ¢
3   \\u00A3      £
4   \\u00A4      ¤
5   \\u00A5      ¥
6   \\u20A1      ¢
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `as.character.POSIXt` to 'render' symbols and pad with spaces. Unicode characters in the form "\uxxxx" will be printed as a single character and all others will be larger; then you can filter according to length:

```
# To keep 'single char' symbols e.g. "$":
df %>% filter(nchar(as.character.POSIXt(Symbol)) >= 2)

# Or for 'unicode format' symbols e.g. "\u07fe":
df %>% filter(nchar(as.character.POSIXt(Symbol)) == 1)
```

If you have a long string as a 'symbol' (e.g. "aaaaaaaaaa₣") the padding will be increased and need to be accounted for e.g.

```
# To keep 'single char' symbols e.g. "$":
df %>% filter(nchar(as.character.POSIXt(Symbol)) >= 11)

# Or for 'unicode format' symbols e.g. "\u07fe":
df %>% filter(nchar(as.character.POSIXt(Symbol)) <= 10)
```